# What is the source for this quote from Ibn Taymiyyah?

Tags: source-identification, islamic-philosophy, aqidah, divine-attributes, ibn-taymiyyah

> Ibn Taymiyyah  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him wrote, "This is why
> the early Muslim generations and all the Imaams did not declare that
> the Quran and all the Attributes of Allaah to be 'other than' Him, nor
> did they declare that they are not other than Him. That is because the
> indication of the terms 'other than' is general/ambiguous; it could
> indicate the meaning 'detached' or 'separate', and accordingly, it
> would mean that all or part of the attribute belonging to the object
> of qualification are not included in the "other". (On the other hand)
> it could mean something conceivable, without conceiving something
> apart from the other. This is why the adherents of philosophical
> speculation (Ahl An-Nathar) disagreed about the use of the term 'other
> than' in this context. The difference in opinion revolved around the
> linguistic indication of the terms; however, this difference of
> opinion gave rise to a number of misconceptions with relation to the
> Divine Attributes that cannot be eliminated except with careful
> investigation of the linguistic indication of the terms in order to
> clear all potential ambiguities, as explained in detail in other
> works.
>
> This is why a differentiation is made between saying: 'the Attributes
> are other than the Essence,' and saying 'the Attributes of Allaah are
> other than Allaah.' The latter is false because the name ‘Allaah’
> includes His Attributes, unlike the ‘Essence', which does not include
> His Attributes. This is why it cannot be said that the Attributes of
> Allaah are additional to Allaah, even though it is said that the
> Attributes are additional to the Essence, because the intended meaning
> is that the Attributes are additional to the affirmed Divine Essence
> which exists without the Attributes. On the contrary, the Divine
> Essence is qualified with those Attributes which are inseparable from
> it. Neither the Attributes are without the Essence, nor is the Essence
> without the Attributes." ([Source](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/282904/elaboration-required-if-one-says-allaahs-attributes-are-other-than-him))

Comment: Since unfortunately the editors at Islamweb rarely mention the name of ibn Taymiyyah's books and this is an English translation it's rather hard to find the source, as even the fatwa numbers of English translated fatwas don't match their Arabic original. And having at least the latter is essential for a search.